# Visual Studio Code se abre dos veces.-

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio

Después de un reinicio inesperado del ordenador, y teniendo abierto el Visual Studio Code antes, ahora cuando lo abro, se abren dos vsc, no dos pestañas, si no dos vsc.
Ya me ocurrió en otra ocasión y no recuerdo la solución, ¿podeis ayudarme?
Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que la pregunta se relacione con python y/o c#, pero como posible solución proba verificar que no tengas la opción de doble click automático activado.

Para verificar esto accede a un explorador de Windows (WIN + E), y en el menú de arriba pulsá sobre **Vista** y luego sobre el botón de Opciones.

En la ventana que se abre, comprobá que en la parte de en medio (Acciones al hacer clic en un elemento) está marcada la opción **Doble clic para abrirlo (un clic para seleccionarlo)**

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Gracias! eres todo un genio.